# Ocultar Elementos del Sidebar ( Yii 2 - RBAC)

Tags: php, yii2, yii, hide

Ante todo, un cordial saludo a todos,

Tengo el siguiente problema, y es que aunque tengo ya configurado los  permisos necesarios para no acceder a ciertos modulos mediante el Widget de Yii 2 RBAC, Sin embargo ahora necesito ocultar las opciones cargadas en el Sidebar.

```
     ['label' => 'Módulo Usuarios',  'icon' => 'user', 'url' => ['/user-list']
```

¿Como podria ocultar este label, aplicando alguna configuración existente en el Widget RBAC de Yii 2?

De antemano, agradecido

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que has implementado es el RBAC descrito aquí:

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization#rbac

En esta otra sección puedes ver cómo comprobar un permiso manualmente:

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization#access-check

```
if (\Yii::$app->user->can('createPost')) {
    // create post
}
```

Por lo tanto, en tu sidebar tienes dos opciones.

A) Puedes usar la condición de más arriba a la hora de generar el array de elementos incluidos en el menú.
B) Puedes directamente usar el atributo `visible` si usas un widget de menú de Yii, ejemplo:

```
[
  'label' => 'Módulo Usuarios',  
  'icon' => 'user', 
  'url' => ['/user-list'],
  'visible' => \Yii::$app->user->can('gestionarUsuarios'),
]
```